# Run-time error '13' Type mismatch when looking in cell range

Tags: vba, excel

I work for an automotive company as a logistic administrative and I want to record a macro that allows me to look for a range of cells which contain the numbers of the operations and delete the files that are related to retail clients (keeping the fleet clients ones).

Fleets operations start with 01RN92, 01RN94, 01RR, and 01RB. The other ones are for retail clients.

The part of the code that is throwing the error is the if loop in this part of the code:

```
Dim celda As Object
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("B2:B200")

For Each celda In rng
    valor = celda.Value
    If valor Like "01RN92*" Or valor Like "01RN94*" Or valor Like "01RB*" Or valor Like "01RR*" Then
        celda.Interior.Color = 65535
    Else
        celda.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next celda
```

I need help. What am I missing here and how can I solve it?

Thank you very much.
Kind regards.

Comment: Which line gives you the error?

Comment: Hi. This one:If valor Like "01RN92*" Or valor Like "01RN94*" Or valor Like "01RB*" Or valor Like "01RR*" Then
        celda.Interior.Color = 65535

Comment: Step through the code and check for which cell you are getting that error. Then physically check that cell and see if there is any formula error like "#N/A" "#DIV/0!" etc

Answer (score 1):

Formula errors in column B's values will cause this issue. The following rework would skip them:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("B2:B200")

For y = rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
    With rng.Cells(y)
    valor = .Value
    If Not (IsError(valor)) Then
        If valor Like "01RN92*" Or valor Like "01RN94*" Or valor Like "01RB*" Or valor Like "01RR*" Then
            .Interior.Color = VBYellow
        Else
            .EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End If
    End With
Next
```

**Note: it's best practice to delete from the bottom up, rather than top down, in order to be sure that you delete every row that should be.**

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the Stackoverflow. You are most probably getting that error because there is a formula error in one of the cells.

Here is a simple way to reproduce it and identify the culprit cell.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim celda As Range, rng As Range
    Dim CellAddress As String

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1

    With ws
        Set rng = .Range("B2:B200")

        For Each celda In rng
            valor = celda.Value
            If valor Like "01RN92*" Or valor Like "01RN94*" Or valor Like "01RB*" Or valor Like "01RR*" Then
                celda.Interior.Color = 65535
            Else
                celda.EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next celda
    End With

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    If Not celda Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox Err.Description, vbInformation, "Check Cell " & celda.Address
    Else
        MsgBox Err.Description, vbInformation
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

As mentioned in the comments above, Step through the code and check for which cell you are getting that error. Then physically check that cell and see if there is any formula error like "#N/A" "#DIV/0!"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was that some of the cells were #N/A, because the first part of the macro has some formulas on it.

Thank you very much, I'll keep improving the macro to avoid those #N/A's and make it work perfectly.